# How to slide image and text at the same time

Tags: html, css

I want to slide thumbnail image and text at same time and control buttons. Can anybody show me how to do this. I don't want bootstrap slider because i already have two sliders on that page.

My HTML Code

```
<div class="events">
<img src="slide-1.jpg" />
<h5>Date</h5>
<h2>Event name</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse cursus pellentesque nunc, in eros liaculis id cursus consectetur.</p>
<a class="readmore" href="#">Read more</a>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.events {width:400px;}
.readmore {padding:8px 15px; background:#ff6000; color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: i think ,you answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218554/how-to-slide-images-text-at-the-same-time-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I worked up an example with one slide, just make sure which ever slide you want to slide is the first element in the slides container. Hope this helps.

The text is centered in the image, and the image is kind of log, so you have to scroll down a bit to see it in action.

```js
$(".slide-out").click(function(){
  $(".slides .slide:first").toggleClass("slide-left");
});
```

```css
.slide {
  position: relative;
  transition: all 1s;
  left: 0;
}

.slide-left {
  transition: all 1s;
  left: -100%;  
}

.slides {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slide img {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.slide .caption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 20px;
}

h4, p {
  color: #fff !important;  
}

button {
  position: fixed;  
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="controls">
      <button class="slide-out">Toggle Slide</button>
    </div>
    <div class="slides">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://previews.123rf.com/images/dvu/dvu0905/dvu090500006/4894562-compressed-orange-isolated-on-a-black-background-Stock-Photo.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Slide header</h4>
          <p>Whatever caption you want</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```